# msbuild /t:metrics fails on azuredevops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines

While running below command for the solution it works fine on command line on on-premise.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" test.sln /t:Metrics -p:Configuration=Debug -p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

The task used in the pipeline is :

```
- task: CmdLine@2
            inputs:
              script: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" Test.sln /p:AzureDevOps=true /verbosity:d /t:Metrics -p:Configuration=Debug -p:Platform="Any CPU"'
              workingDirectory: 'C:\a\1\s\Ett\Test'
              failOnStderr: true
```

Also tried the task :

```
- task: VSBuild@1
            displayName: CodeMetrics    
            inputs:
             solution: '**\CN.Test.sln'
             msbuildArgs: '/t:Metrics'      
             platform: 'Any CPU'
             configuration: 'debug'
             createLogFile: true
             logFileVerbosity: 'detailed'
```

However fails to run from the pipeline with below error :

***The target "Metrics" does not exist in the project***

Comment: Where is the target `metrecs` defined? Is there a custom tool installed on your machine that has put a set of targets files in your mrbuild folder that are missing on your build server? If you run the agent on your own machine, does the error persist?

Comment: @jessehouwing : to define the target 'Metrics'  the nuget 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Metrics' is installed in each project.

Comment: Then you probably need to run `/t:restore;metrics` as that target won't be available until after the packages have been restored.

Comment: also tried making my machine as build agent, still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The target 'Metrics' the nuget 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Metrics' is installed in each project.

This is the key. That target won't be available until after you've restored the nuget packages. The packages will have been restored on your local machine though.

For your build pipeline to work make sure you perform a restore first, either as part of the existing invocation of MSBuild, or as a seperate step.

```
MSBuild /t:restore;metrics ...
```

Or:

```
Msbuild /t:restore ...
Msbuild /t:metrics ...
```

Comment: Yes restore did the magic ! thanks @jessehouwing,  now the task is like                                 - task: VSBuild@1
            displayName: CodeMetrics  VSBuild            
            inputs:
             solution: '**\Test.sln'
             msbuildArgs: '/t:restore;metrics'      
             platform: 'Any CPU'
             configuration: 'Debug'

Answer (score -1):

Based on your description and concern, in your second shared task, for **msbuildArgs: '/t:Metrics'** in the task, the specified target File structure '/t:Metrics' is not completed, that's why you met this issue.

To solve this issue, you could define the target to folder level where the spevified csproj file located.

**For example**: File structure: xx->xxx->metrics ->xx.csproj

msbuildArgs: ”/t:xx\xxx\metrics“

For more information, you could also refer to the doc: [How to: Build specific targets in solutions by using MSBuild.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2019) .